# Convert the continuous values of grades into classes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe int_stdf (Fig. 1) and I need to do the following:

Consider the values in G1, G2 and G3 being >= 10 as pass(1) and < 10 as fail(0) and encode them into binary values. Print head of dataframe to check the values.

```
        G1  G2  G3
number          
  0     5   6   6
  1     5   5   6
  2     7   8   10
  3     15  14  15
  4     6   10  10
  5     15  15  15
```

Fig. 1

```
        G1  G2  G3
number          
  0     0   0   0
  1     0   0   0
  2     0   0   1
  3     1   1   1
  4     0   1   1
  5     1   1   1
```

Fig. 2

So I should get something like (Fig. 2):

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: `df.ge(10).astype(int)`

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment of some sort. What have you done? Please post your code and explain why you are not happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df >= 10, 1, 0), columns=df.columns)

   G1  G2  G3
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   1   1
4   0   1   1
5   1   1   1
```